# f(x) is a non increasing function with range (1,0]. Now can I prove analytical that \log(f(x)) is a convex function of x?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function f(x). And it is non-increasing with respect to x, for $x>0$. And also I know that f(x) is convex. Now the range of f(x) is bounded by $(1,0]$. Now, I want to prove analytically $log(f(x))$ is convex. I am not finding out any theorem regarding that type of problem. 
I tried to solve by definition that $log(f(\lambda*x1+(1-\lambda)*x2))\le \lambda*log(f(x1))+(1-\lambda)*log(f(x2))$. But it was too complex because of the nature of my $f(x)$. I also tried by taking second derivative of $log(f(x))$ but no luck because of the nature of $f(x)$. So, I am looking for any theorem or special case that I can apply on that. Thanks.

Comment: Being log-convex is very unusual.

Comment: I even plotted this. log(f(x))showed convexity numerically.

Comment: If it's log convex, that isn't determined by the properties you've stated. You need something a lot stronger than that.

Comment: sorry for asking. What do you mean by stronger? Do you mean the convexity of f(x) or any property regarding f(x). Because I know the maximum value of f(x) is 0.5

Comment: It would help if you just laid out what the function is. It's okay if it's complicated, we can handle it.

Comment: Thank you. My function is : $log \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{\varepsilon _i}\left( {Q{{\left( {{a_i} + {b_i}\sqrt x } \right)}^2}} \right)} } \right)$ Where, $Q(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_x^\infty  {{e^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}du} $ . I have to prove my $log(f(x))$ is convex for all $a_i,b_i, x>0$.    ***** it is to be noted that I found $\log (Q{\left( {a + b\sqrt x } \right)^2})$ is convex for all $a_i,b_i, x>0$. I dont know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better if you put it in the post and explain what the $\epsilon_i$ are as well.

Comment: I apologize for that, my $\sum \epsilon_i=1$.  I wanted to edit the post but could not do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=x^2$$
with $f(1)=\frac 12$.

$f $ is not increasing at $(0,1]$
and

$$f((0,1])=(0,1]$$

but

$$x\mapsto \ln(f(x))=2\ln(x)$$
is not convex at $(0,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean decreasing by non increasing.

Comment: Yes it is decreasing. I even plotted this. log(f(x))showed convexity numerically.